# Jest is hung there

Tags: jestjs

I have a project using jest. It's running good historically. After 1 year when I open it, somehow jest is hung. No info, no error, not proceed. (See pic) Any insights?

[image: jest hung pic]

Comment: Without any further information it will be hard to impossible to figure out why this not work anymore. maybe you should start with updating jest to the latest version.

Comment: I did "npm install jest -g" so I assume I got latest jest. Yes, the jest is just hung there without any output printed. Is there any "debug mode" or parameter I can try?

Comment: I have a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212843/testing-expressjs-endpoint-with-jest

Answer (score 0):

Jest runs the tests with a multithreaded approach that might sometimes run into a deadlock. The same happened to me on Git-bash when I used to run my projects in a windows environment. Try adding a

> -- -i

to your test command to run it without using multithreading and see if it solves the problem.