# Testing ExpressJS endpoint with Jest

Tags: express, testing, tdd, jestjs

I'm trying to test an endpoint from my express application using Jest. I'm migrating from Mocha to try out Jest to improve the speed. However, my Jest test does not close? I'm at a loss...

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
const app = require('../../../index');
const request = require('supertest')(app);

it('should serve the apple-app-site-association file /assetlinks.json GET', async () => {
  const response = await request.get('/apple-app-site-association')
  expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So the only thing I could think for this failing is that you might be missing the package `babel-preset-env`.

In any case there are two other ways to use supertest:

```
it('should serve the apple-app-site-association file /assetlinks.json GET', () => {
  return request.get('/apple-app-site-association').expect(200)
})
```

or

```
it('should serve the apple-app-site-association file /assetlinks.json GET', () => {
    request.get('/apple-app-site-association').then(() => {
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
        done()
    })
})
```

`async` is the fancy solution, but is also the one that has more requirements. If you manage to find what was the issue let me know :).

(Reference for my answer: http://www.albertgao.xyz/2017/05/24/how-to-test-expressjs-with-jest-and-supertest/)

Comment: Unfortunately not. It still doesn't exit. The issue is something to do with closing the connection to mongoose I think?

Comment: why dont you mock mongoose call?, you can do that with 
jest.mock('mongoose', () => ({
  themethodyouuse: jest.fn()
}))

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

Answer (score 0):

```
it("should serve the apple-app-site-association file /assetlinks.json GET", async () => {
  await request
    .get("/apple-app-site-association")
    .send()
    .expect(200);
});
```

if your configuration setup is correct this code should work.